# Counting matching rows in IQueryable

Tags: c#, beginner, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

I'm designing a basic ticketing system using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework.

I'm passing a `DbSet<TicketModel>` into a method as an `IQueryable<TicketModel>` that adds to a category counter based on a couple columns.

Tickets have four different states and an age. I need to display counters for the `total` as well as `each of these states` and counters for those `between 60 and 90 days old` and those `above 90 days old`.

As I understand it, operating on `IQueryable` is more efficient as it actually changes the query sent to the database. Operating on an actual `List` pulls the entire table then works on it. However, LINQ-to-Entities only works with columns in the database. How can I get around this?

Model:

```
public class TicketModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public StatusType Status { get; set; }
    public enum StatusType { Open, Resolved, Responded, Archived };
    public DateTime DateOfCreation { get; set; }
    public bool Is60To90DaysOld
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan age = DateTime.Today - DateOfCreation;
            return (age.Days >= 60 && age.Days < 90);
        }
    }
    public bool Is90DaysOld
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan age = DateTime.Today - DateOfCreation;
            return (age.Days >= 90);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
// Avoid using fully-qualified name for StatusType
using static MyProject.Models.TicketModel;
public class TicketCountersViewModel
{
    // Counters for each type of ticket
    public struct TicketCounts
    {
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public int Open { get; set; }
        public int Responded { get; set; }
        public int Resolved { get; set; }
        public int Archived { get; set; }
        public int Age60To90 { get; set; }
        public int Age90Plus { get; set; }
    }

    public TicketCounts Counters;

    public TicketCountersViewModel(IQueryable<TicketModel> ticketList)
    {
        Counters.Total = ticketList.Count();
        Counters.Open = ticketList.Count(e => e.Status == StatusType.Open);
        Counters.Responded = ticketList.Count(e => e.Status == StatusType.Responded);
        Counters.Resolved = ticketList.Count(e => e.Status == StatusType.Resolved);
        Counters.Archived = ticketList.Count(e => e.Status == StatusType.Archived);
        // Can't use LINQ-to-Entities here -- Is60To90DaysOld and Is90DaysOld aren't columns in database
        List<TicketModel> list = ticketList.ToList();
        Counters.Age60To90 = list.Count(e => e.Is60To90DaysOld);
        Counters.Age90Plus = list.Count(e => e.Is90DaysOld);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class TicketsController
{
    private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new TicketCountersViewModel(db.Tickets));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Counters.Total = ticketList.Count();
> Counters.Open = ticketList.Count(e => e.Status == StatusType.Open);
> Counters.Responded = ticketList.Count(e => e.Status == StatusType.Responded);
> Counters.Resolved = ticketList.Count(e => e.Status == StatusType.Resolved);
> Counters.Archived = ticketList.Count(e => e.Status == StatusType.Archived);
> ```

You have so many counters there that you should really consider using a `GroupBy` on the `Status` column.

---

> ```
> // Can't use LINQ-to-SQL here -- Is60To90DaysOld and Is90DaysOld aren't columns in database
> List<TicketModel> list = ticketList.ToList();
> Counters.Age60To90 = list.Count(e => e.Is60To90DaysOld);
> Counters.Age90Plus = list.Count(e => e.Is90DaysOld);
> ```

This part could also benefit from another `GroupBy` if you added one more property `Age` and a helper enum:

```
public enum Age
{ 
    Unknown,
    Between60And90Days,
    GreaterOrEqual90Days
}
```

The new property could replace the other two as they are mutually exclusive anyway:

```
public Age Age
{
    get 
    {
        TimeSpan age = DateTime.Today - DateOfCreation;

        if (age.Days >= 60 && age.Days < 90) return Age.Between60And90Days;
        if (age.Days >= 90) return Age.GreaterOrEqual90Days;

        return Age.Unknown;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never messed with `GroupBy`, but from looking at examples like [this](https://i.imgur.com/r8wwoNv.png), I can't figure out how it's any better than using a foreach and a switch block to just check each enum and add to a counter as you go. What you're getting at is that by calling five `Count`s, I'm iterating through the list 5 times, which is bad, right?

Comment: @Sinjai _I can't figure out how it's any better than using a foreach and a switch block to just **check each enum**_ - you have answered your question yourself.  You need to write a count per enum value. Should you add a new value to the enum then you need to extend the foreach that counts them. This is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Good call! I just wanted to make sure they were functionally the same before adding a bunch of code I don't understand. I could alternatively loop through the enum myself, but I suppose that would be reinventing the wheel. Is executing the queryable down to a list still my best bet?

Comment: I really can't figure out how to use `GroupBy` here. Could you please post an example?

Comment: @Sinjai `ticketList.GroupBy(x => x.Status)` that's all you need ;-]

Comment: I must be dense, but that groups them... then how do I get the counts for each grouping?

Comment: @Sinjai how about this? `ticketList.GroupBy(x => x.Status).Select(g => new { Status = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })`

Comment: I appreciate your patience. That gets me the number of each type, but [how do I know which counter to set?](https://hastebin.com/uyajerufej.cs)

Comment: @Sinjai I'm not quite sure what you mean by _which counter to set_? Could you add more code to the example showing what you are going to achieve? We'll figure this out ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64078/discussion-between-sinjai-and-t3chb0t).